# How to use ScalaTest Matcher to Test Failure Exception Type?

Tags: scala, scalatest

Given a scala function that can produces Failures:

```
def testableFunction(x: Int) : Try[Int] = {
  if(x == 0)
    Failure[Int](new IllegalArgumentException("0 is bad"))
  else if(x == 1)
    Failure[Int](new Exception("1 not so good either"))
  else
    Success(42)
}
```

**How can [scalatest matchers](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers) be used to test the Exception type?**

I'm looking for something of the form:

```
testableFunction(0).failure.type should be IllegalArgumentException

testableFunction(1).failure.type should be Exception
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.10/org/scalatest/TryValues.html - https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingAnObjectsClass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mix in the `TryValues` trait:

```
class ExampleTestSpec extends Matchers with TryValues {
  ...
  testableFunction(0).failure.exception shouldBe a [IllegalArgumentException]
}
```